# Is there a way to create private fields with function constructors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, we have the concept of classes which is "syntactic sugar" for functions. My idea is that everything we can do with classes, we can also do with function constructors. Is this true? And if this is true, is there a way to create private fields with a function constructor?

For classes, private fields are declared using the hash symbol (#).

Comment: `Is this true?` No, classes are not merely syntactic sugar. There's a few things that classes do which can't be done with function constructors, with private fields being a prime example.

Comment: You might be interested in [using WeakMaps](https://modernweb.com/private-variables-in-javascript-with-es6-weakmaps/).

Comment: As mentioned, you can have something *pretty similar* with a WeakMap - it's not exactly the same, and requires more code, but does offer true privacy via a closure.

Comment: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEASCmIQHsDqyBOIAm0DeAUNMQBaIrQC80ATAAwDcRxAxAO6Y5XQCMjBAXyA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.17.12&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) uses WeakMaps as well

Comment: By the way, there are alternatives: you can set the property as `{writable: false}`, you can omit the setter, etc...

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light on this!

Answer (score 0):

Classes aren't just syntactical sugar anymore because of 3 reasons:

- They have private fields
- All classes have a special property `[[isClassConstructor]]`
- You can use `instanceof` with classes but not with function constructors

Comment: I agree with 1 & 2 but not 3. You can use `instanceof` on any function. [Basic example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABQKYCcDOCAUBKRAbwFgAoRRKACxkwDowBDAW1UQF5EAiAIzh64BuMgF8yZCAmwAbVHWlwA5jjCoA7igzYkMMJiiNIqOME1YEeIA)